# Serving static files dynamically by domain name with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Assume a Spring Boot application serving static files by default from its resources folder. The resources folder looks something like this:

```
~/resources
~/resources/test.txt
~/resources/example.com/test.txt
~/resources/anotherexample.com/test.txt
```

Now, when I call http://localhost:8080/test.txt the application returns `~/resources/test.txt`.

In production the application is running at `example.com` and `anotherexample.com`.

My question is, how do I have to configure or extend the application to achieve, that static content is served from different locations based on the request's domain:

- http://example.com/test.txt serves `~/resources/example.com/test.txt`
- http://anotherexample.com/test.txt serves `~/resources/anotherexample.com/test.txt`

---

What I already found out:

- There is a *ResourceHandlerRegistry*
- It is possible to override *addResourceHandlers* in the application's spring configuration to manipulate the resource handler registry.
- There are *ResourceResolver*s in a resolver chain, which somehow resolve the internal paths by their URL.

---

What I am missing is how to connect those parts. Afaik I should write an implementation for *ResourceResolver* and put it to the *ResourceHandlerRegistry*'s resolver chain. What would such an implementation look like and how is it provided to the resource handler registry?